# A list of string separate with space transform to int with comma instead

Tags: python, list

The original data:

```
a = [ ['1 2 3'] , [ '4 5 6'] ]
```

The data I want:

```
a = [ [1, 2, 3], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]
```

How can I transform it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use List Comprehension:

```
 a = [[int(i) for i in  x[0].split()] for x in a ]
```

Ouput:

```
 [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [
    ['1 2 3'], 
    ['4 5 6']
]

b = [
    list(map(int, x[0].split())) 
    for x in a
]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```